# Join two table using CTE and store the result in another CTE

Tags: sql, hive, common-table-expression

I want to join master table and transaction table using CTE. I tried to do that but I don't know how to utilise the query result to join another table.

```
with CTE_base as (
select
account_number,
orgn_acct,
product_type,
load_date as report_date,
min(concat(case when 
substr(load(cast(acc_open_date as string),6,'0'),1,2)>'30' then '19'else '20' end,
substr(load(cast(acc_open_date as string),6,'0'),1,2),'-',
substr(load(cast(acc_open_date as string),6,'0'),3,2),'-',
substr(load(cast(acc_open_date as string),6,'0'),5,2)))) as open_date
from master
where 
product_type <400 
and product_type not between 290 and 390
and datediff(load_date,concat(case when 
substr(load(cast(acc_open_date as string),6,'0'),1,2)>'30' then '19'else '20' end,
substr(load(cast(acc_open_date as string),6,'0'),1,2),'-',
substr(load(cast(acc_open_date as string),6,'0'),3,2),'-',
substr(load(cast(acc_open_date as string),6,'0'),5,2))) <=398

group by load_date,orgn_acct,product_type,account_number)

select * from CTE_base)master

inner join(
with CTE_fees as (select
trans_code,
march_code,
account_num,
load_date,
case when (
(trans_code =253)
and (march_code =12)
then "annual fee")
end as fee_type)
from transaction)
select * from CTE_fees) fees

on fees.account_num =master.account_number
where datediff(fees.load_date,master.open_date )<=397
```

how would I join another table on the result of inner join of two tables?
I read online that it can be done using multiple CTE not sure

1. how can I store the result of two queries in another CTE?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read, and to write.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: working on HIVE

Comment: CTE results are not something where data is "stored".

Answer (score 2):

Use multiple CTEs to reference CTEs already defined.  Example below:

```
WITH A
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.TableA

),

B AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.TableB

),

C AS (

    SELECT *
    FROM A
        JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
)

--display cte based on B and A being joined
SELECT *
FROM C
```

Comment: How to store inner join result into another CTE ? Because I want to join another table  with this result set

Comment: The CTE `C` shows how two other CTEs can be joined together.